# Confusion about the generating function for a regular expression

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions, regular-expressions

Given a regex `A = (a*b)*`, I want to compute the Generating Function that enumerate this regex.

The formula for the GF of that regex is `1/(1-z/(1-z)) = (1-z)/(1-2z)`. Then I can compute the sequence that this GF represents is `a(n) = 2^n - 2^(n-1)`. Based on that, I can compute that the number of 3-character strings that match regex A is `a(3) = 4`. However, I can only list 2 of them which are `aab`, `bbb`. I tried with 4 and 5-character strings and that does not feel right as well.

So my question is, am I misunderstanding anything here? If yes, I would be happy if you point it out.

Thank you,

Comment: $\alpha^*$ means _any_ number of $\alpha$, including zero, so $A = \{\varepsilon, b, ab, bb, aab, abb, bab, bbb, \ldots\}$.

Comment: @dtldarek yeah, I know about that. I'm counting all the strings that have the length of 3 and match the regex. However, the formula doesn't seem right.

Comment: (a*b)* accept these four 3-character strings $aab, (ab)b, b(ab), bbb$.

Comment: Ah, yeah. I got it @achillehui, my stupid :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

- Let $A = (a^*b)^*$ and $A' = \Sigma^* \setminus A$ (i.e. the complement of $A$).
- Observe that any word $w$ that ends with the letter $b$ belongs to $A$.
- Observe that $A' = \Sigma^*a$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thank you, it does help :)